# Acessing Javascript variable in .aspx file showing elements conditionally

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Having this .html snippet:

```
<body>
    <div id="testDiv">
       This always appears
    </div>
    <%
    if(step==1)
    {%>

    html code

    <% } 
    if (step==2) 
    {
    %>
    other html code
    <% } %>
</body>
```

How can I access the variable "step", present in a `.js` file, imported using a `script` tag, in order to show HTML elements conditionally?
I am trying to somehow simulate the `*ngIf` function of Angular2, in AspX.
Thanks!

Comment: You can set step value into hidden field from javascript code and that can be use backend side as well aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this and create a javascript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step = <%= step %>;
    alert(step);
</script>
```

You can also use a ScriptManager

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "setValue", "var step = " + step + ";", true);
```

In both cases `step` is available in .js files.

Comment: Putting that code, either in .aspx file or in the .js file gives me expected expressions in the `<%=` parts